# The selenium script developed on C#/VS/Window can be run using Safari/MacOS on BrowserStack?

Tags: c#, macos, selenium, safari, browserstack

I developed one selenium automation script for our project Web UI using C# on Nunit framework, Visual Studio, and Window 10. There are totally 70 cases, and all cases passed using browser Chrome/Firefox on Window 10 on browserstack. However, most of 70 cases failed using Safari/Mac OS on Browserstack. **I wonder if the selenium script developed on C#/VS/Window can be run using Safari/Mac OS on BrowserStack?**

Answer (score 0):

Selenium script developed using c# can indeed be executed using Safari/Mac OS on browserstack. You can execute a sample test from this link to confirm the same as well.
Link-https://github.com/browserstack/browserstack-local-csharp.
Do you encounter any exception or error stack trace locally when the tests fail?

Comment: I use browserstack.local=false, and sent the script to browserstack server to run the script

Comment: Could you tell me where can I get the BrowserStackLocal.exe and package?